# New column with value equal to first column value that is not null

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | NULL | 5 |
| 1 | NULL | 9 | 2 |

I want to add column D which looks at some columns A, B, and C and is equal to the value in the first one that is not null. I also want a column with the column I ended up choosing:

| id | A | B | C | D | Choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | C |
| 7 | 2 | NULL | 5 | 2 | A |
| 1 | NULL | 9 | 2 | 9 | B |

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: `CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN 'a' WHEN b IS NULL THEN 'b' WHEN c IS NULL THEN 'c' ELSE '-' END AS choice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the column values e.g.

```
declare @demo table (id int, A int null, B int null, C int null);
insert into @demo (id, A,B,C) values
( 3,   NULL, NULL,  1),
( 7,   2,    NULL,  5),
( 1,   NULL, 9,     2);

select id, A,B,C, COALESCE(A,B,C,0) as firstNonNull
from @demo
```

Edit: as has been pointed out in the comments the OP wanted both the value and the name of the column in which that value was found. Here is my amended example

```
select ID, A, B, C, COALESCE(A, B, C) as D,
    case COALESCE(A, B, C)
        when A THEN 'A'
        when B THEN 'B'
        when C THEN 'C'
        else 'None'
    end as Choice
from @demo
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the first non null _value_, it wants the column name of the first non null value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP wants *both*.

Comment: Why the "ELSE 0" rather than letting it just default to NULL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - look again at the OP's desired results and their statement of the problem "and is equal to the value in the first one that is not null". They wanted the value in the column.
By the same token, MatBailie has pointed out - they did want both

Comment: @MatBailie - Re the default -  I've only provided an example. Given that the OP wanted a value, it seemed reasonable to give one.  
As to the wanting both, I read the Choice column as being related to user input, probably incorrectly, in which case your CASE statement is appropriate